# Launching Safari in private mode using WebDriver

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, safari

I would like to start browser in private mode right away.

```
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver ();
```

I tried set: **Preferences** -> **General** -> **Safari opens with** : **a new private window**

Is there possibility for Safari? I know how it works on other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest [`SafariDriver` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/about_webdriver_for_safari?language=objc), there's really no need to start an explicit private browsing window, as the automated sessions always start with a clean slate:

> Test execution is confined to special automation windows that are isolated from normal browsing windows, user settings, and preferences. You can recognize these windows by their orange Smart Search field. Like a private browsing session, an automation session always starts from a clean slate. It can’t access Safari’s browsing history, AutoFill data, or other sensitive information available in a normal browsing session. These isolated sessions also help to ensure that tests are unaffected by a previous test session’s persistent state.

This is consistent with my experience with the more recent SafariDriver implementations as well.